# Azure Function App - No header is present

Tags: jquery, azure, azure-functions

I am evaluating [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). In an attempt to do this, I have a web page that runs on localhost. I want to use JQuery to call an Azure Function and display the result. In an attempt to do this, I have the following HTML:

```
<button onclick="return onTestClick();">Test</button>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
  function onTestClick() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://[my-function-app].azurewebsites.net/api/[My-Function]?code=[myCode]&name=bill", 
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(xhr);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

When I click the button, the `error` event handler is triggered. In the console window, I can see the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://[my-function-app].azurewebsites.net/api/[My-Function[?code=[myCode]&name=bill.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My question is, how do I call an Azure Function from jQuery that's running on localhost? The Azure Function itself is just the sample function provided.

Comment: Did you try to enable CORS in the Function App Settings?

Comment: Please fix title to reflect the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable CORS in the Azure App Service.  Details and screenshots are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript/#corsconfig).

Comment: Note: from a Function App, you'll first need to go to 'Function App Settings' and 'Go to App Service settings' to get to the UI that matches this link.

Answer (score 0):

Please note you have to remove all others allow origin type if you are adding * on it, Because i have successfully wasted my 3-4 hours from here and there adding localhost and all, Everything got failed and nothing worked finally i did as it was instructed, I removed all the allow origin and within fraction of second i got the output.